# Typescript: Module as return type?

Tags: typescript

There's a module representing an object I need as return type. Typescript is balking at me doing `public myThingGetter(): Promise<ThisIsTheModuleName>`. What are my options here?

Comment: Have you tried `public myThingGetter(): Promise<typeof ThisIsTheModuleName>`?

Answer (score 2):

> public myThingGetter(): Promise. What are my options here?

`Promise<ThisIsTheModuleName>` is an annotation in the *type* declaration space.

I think you need to use `Promise<typeof ThisIsTheModuleName>` or alternatively use `import` instead of `var/const` etc.

## More

This is covered here : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/declarationspaces.html